# how to provide default template parameter and template function argument default value in the same time?

Tags: c++, templates

I Have the following code:

```
template <typename Iter, typename STREAM>
void print(Iter b, Iter e, STREAM& strm)
{
    while (b != e)
    {
        strm << *b;
        strm << "   ";
        ++b;
    }
    strm << "\n";
}
```

How to have default value for `strm = std::cout` ?

Comment: `void print(Iter b, Iter e, STREAM& strm = std::cout)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver [No](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9f96a678fa61c71)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Woot.  TIL.

Comment: Does `STREAM` really need to be a template?  Are you planning on writing to stream types other than `std::ostream`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, That is just an exercise which has requirement to provide for any stream type.

Comment: But every stream you can output with, should derive from `std::ostream`!

Comment: @NarekMeta All *standard* output streams derive from `std::ostream`. So, unless you need to support 3rd-party streams that don't derive from `std::ostream`, I would suggest simply dropping the `STREAM` template completely and change `STREAM& strm` to `std::ostream& strm` instead. Then `std::ostream& strm = std::cout` will work.

Comment: Mayn't someone have a class and ```ostream& m_strm``` reference member and just overload ```operator<<()``` which will just call ostream::operator<< ?
No subclassing.
The print should also work for this user-defined "streams"

Comment: @NarekMeta that is certainly a *possibility*, bu is that really part of you *requirement* to support?

Comment: I don't know so decided to cover also that cases :)

Answer (score 5):

If you were to just add `= std::cout`, you'd need to provide the template argument `std::ostream` explicitly when calling the function with two arguments, which is a bit rubbish.

The easiest way to do what you want is to provide a new overload:

```
template <typename Iter>
void print(Iter b, Iter e)
{
    print(b, e, std::cout);
}
```

You could also consider getting rid of `STREAM` entirely; you usually only ever want to stream to a `std::ostream`. There's a reason a bunch of useful types inherit from it.

Comment: Thanks, So simple :)
But I would like to know if there is a way without providing an overload ?

Comment: @NarekMeta Template arguments won't be deduced from default function arguments (there's a chicken and egg problem there) so no not really

Comment: Yeah, I read about it and just wanted to know if there is another way. Thanks for concrete answers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide default for type and for argument:

```
template <typename Iter, typename STREAM = std::ostream>
void print(Iter b, Iter e, STREAM& strm = std::cout);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96706f4b0c6c7c50)

As `std::cout` is not a good default value for other `STREAM`, you probably need to change the default:

```
template <typename STREAM>
STREAM& DefaultStream;

template <>
std::ostream& DefaultStream<std::ostream> = std::cout;
```

and then

```
template <typename Iter, typename STREAM = std::ostream>
void print(Iter b, Iter e, STREAM& strm = DefaultStream<STREAM>);
```

Comment: consider if someone call print like this: ```int *a,*b; print<int*, otherStream>(a,b):```

Comment: yes, but someone looking to that prototype may be confused and think that no matter what is the stream type, the default for that type will be taken if no third argument specified. So, first choice is better. I think you also agree that first is better,

Comment: @NarekMeta what do you think if `int *a, *b; print<int>(a, b, std::cout)`? you can actually not prevent anyone providing mismatched template arguments explicitly for the deduced template parameters. to someone that gives an incorrect template arguments, a compiler error is the best reply. another overload is definitely better, but this is not the reason.

Comment: @NarekMeta: Better default value in place now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also use

```
template <typename Iter, typename STREAM = decltype(std::cout)>
void print(Iter b, Iter e, STREAM& strm = std::cout)
{
  while (b != e)
  {
    strm << *b;
    strm << "   ";
    ++b;
  }
  strm << "\n";
}
```

This works with c++11, but I think that @AsteroidsWithWings's solution is the right way to go (as it is simpler and avoid the necessary redundancy required to define both the template type and argument value)

Comment: consider if someone call print like this: int *a,*b; print<int*, otherStream>(a,b):
Error: trying to assign ostream to otherStream.

Comment: @NarekMeta yes I do agree, that's a trick to break the redundancy coherence. This is another example where redundancy is a bad thing, that is also the reason why I recommended asteroids's solution in my comment.

Comment: Yes, @Picaud, I had understood your point. 
Thanks.